# How to get App Insights to print to console on .NET Core 3.1?

Tags: .net-core, azure-application-insights

I have a .NET Core 3.1 console application, initialized using Host.CreateDefaultBuilder. I have it properly configured and I can see on the Azure Portal that TelemetryClient is correctly uploading all of the events.

For diagnostic purposes, I would like plug into Application Insights so that it prints events passing through it to the console. Ideally I could format it the way I want while it is printed, but that is secondary.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anybody out there has the same question, it is possible to do this by writing your own processor. For example, this code will write to the console exactly what is shown in debug output:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class TelemetryConsoleWritingProcessor : ITelemetryProcessor
    {
        private ITelemetryProcessor Next { get; set; }

        public TelemetryConsoleWritingProcessor(ITelemetryProcessor next) => Next = next;

        public void Process(ITelemetry item)
        {
            byte[] serializedItem = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new ITelemetry[] { item }, false);
            string jsonItem = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(serializedItem);
            Console.WriteLine($"Application Insights Telemetry: {jsonItem}");
            Next.Process(item);
        }
    }
}
```

And register it by doing something like this when you Configure your TelemetryConfiguration:

```
options.TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder.Use(next => new TelemetryConsoleWritingProcessor(next));
```

Though this works, the output is quite verbose for a console. So my personal implementation is targeting specific items types inside of Process() and custom formatting them just for the console.

Hope this helps.